# props.params in Enzyme test

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

Im trying to test my component that makes a getJSON request in the componentWillMount lifecycle method. It has the following code:

```
api.getJSON(`users/${this.props.params.id}`)
            .done((result) => {
                this.setState({user: result});
            });
```

As you can see it uses the props.params.id to make the request. The issue im having is in my test. When I run `npm test` it returns cannot read property of undefined, undefined being the `props.params`. How can I get this object in enzyme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way using enzyme with mocha:
- Install **jsdom** `npm install --save-dev --save-exact jsdom jsdom-global`
- Load the jsdom on your before statement (inside describe)

```
    before(function () {
      this.jsdom = require('jsdom-global')()
    })

    after(function () {
      this.jsdom()
    })
```

- Now in your test use **mount** like this:

```
const someData = {data1:'yyyyyy'};
const wrapper = mount(<YourComponent yourProp={someData} />);
```

In your case "*yourProp*" should be params, this way you can pass data to your properties.
Hope this help.

Comment: Also you need yo have a mocha.opts inside test folder (test\mocha.ops) with this: -r jsdom-global/register. And call mocha with --require option (mocha --require).